# Boolean variable

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

I thought the default value of boolean is false? Why does it print the true statement instead? 
My output is goodbye

```
public class Test {

public static void main (String [] args) {

if(false)
    System.out.print("hello");

else System.out.print("goodbye");
}
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the default value of a boolean variable. The `else` branch executes if the expression inside the `()` evaluates to `false`, which it does in your code. What did you expect it to output? And can you explain why did you expect it to output that?

Comment: What default vale? What `true` statement? What happens? What did you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't use the default value of boolean value.
You always print `System.out.print("goodbye");`, because this section is true.
To achieve this, use the following code

```
public class Test {
    static boolean defaultValue;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Default value is "+defaultValue);
        if(defaultValue)
            System.out.println("hello");
        else 
            System.out.println("goodbye");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What sweeper told you in a comment is correct. You seem to be under a wrong impression regarding the syntax I think. Take the following piece of code you gave as an example.

```java
if (false) {
    System.out.print("hello");
}
```

The code inside the if block will **never** run because the *expression*  `false` will always evaluate to the boolean value false. You are asking Java to do the following: 'hey run this code *if* what I put inside the brackets evaluates to true but what you put inside the brackets will **always** evaluate to false. Thats why java will always run the code inside the else block in your example.

I hope this clears thing up a bit.